# Запись трехмерного json-a через PHP

Tags: php, массивы, json

Доброго времени суток.

У меня небольшая проблема. В одном из полей БД лежит трехмерный json вида:

```
{"250":{"39":{"0": "50"}}}
```

Селектю его из базы

```
...
$db_json_threshold = "SELECT...";
$asd = json_decode($db_json_threshold[0]["rate_threshold"], true);
dev_print($asd);
```

Получаю трехмерный массив, все, как и надо:

```
Array
(
    [250] => Array
        (
            [39] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50
                )

        )

)
```

Помимо всего прочего, у меня имеется другой трехмерный массив, лежит он в переменной $outputArray, имеет такой же вид, что и первый. В итоге, я два этих трехмерных массива складываю:

```
dev_print($asd + $outputArray);
```

Все замечательно, получаю такое:

```
Array
(
    [250] => Array
        (
            [39] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50
                )

        )

    [-1] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

И теперь мне необходимо перезаписать то поле в БД новым трехмерным json-ом, но при:

```
json_encode($outputArray + $asd, true);
```

я получаю такое:

```
{"-1":{"-1":["0"]},"250":{"39":["50"]}}
```

Сравните это с джейсоном, который я написал вверху этого поста, чтобы не дублироваться. В общем, в конечном массиве ключ перезатирается, и вместо, например, {"0":"50"}, я получаю ["50"], что для моей задачи абсолютно неприемлемо. Пытался придать ключу "0" стринговое значение, через кавычки или (String)"0", - все безуспешно. Как мне устранить этот произвол при записи, при json_encode? Заранее спасибо!

UPD:

Проблема решилась. Путем экспериментов оказалось, что функция json_encode автоматически группирует массив в объект, если его ключи идут по порядку. В моем случае ключ единичный, имеет значение 0. Если добавлю еще ключ 1, со значением 25, например, будет уже так: ["50", "25"]. Но если добавлю еще ключ 50 со значением 100, будет уже так: {"0":"50", "1":"25", "50":"100"}. Вот такие вот дела )

Etki - спасибо большое за отклик. Не слышал о таком, обязательно прочитаю про это.

Comment: Преобразовывал все к обьектам, пытался делать всяческие манипуляции, ничего не выходит. Последний массив всегда остается обьектом, он всегда в квадратных скобках. Я в отчаянии. Хорошее начало рабочей недели (

Comment: Попробуйте передать вторым параметром `json_encode()` константу `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`.